# How to execute my if loop only once in python?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm using a **if-loop** to place an order to my console , but after condition is met it's getting printed several times.

```
if len(pos_df.columns) == 0 and len(ord_df.columns) == 0:
   for i in range(0,len(bricks_counts)):
       if bricks_counts[i] == -23 and red_neg == True:
           placeCoverOrder(ticker,"sell",quantity,high_down)
           print("sell order placed {}".format(ticker))
           break
```

I want this loop to be executed only once , means it should run only once in the first iteration and it shouldn't run in the second iteration(the if-loop shoould become false in the second iteration).

Any help would be very much helpful for me and must be appreciated.
Adding some extra line's of code's will also be accepted. :)

Comment: What's inside `placeCoverOrder()` method? Does it call this block of code?

Comment: Do you have other blocks of code that contain `print("sell order placed {}".format(ticker))`?

Comment: Yes ```placeCoverOrder()``` call's this block of code when if-loop is True.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of enumerate (idx,val) in for loop where you can fetch index and make sure it's value when gets updated then return. I'm not quite sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: Hey can you explain with some code as example.

Comment: strrl = ['A','B','C','D']

for sidx,sval in enumerate(strrl):
    if sidx == 0:
        print(sval)
    else:
        break

Comment: What this is, is I am making use of first iteration of loop only, and you can write your own logic for this, other than that it will break.